# How would I cache the location of the user with this geolocation script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation

How would I go about caching the location of the user so it doesn't repeatedly ask for user's location when they hit the back button or visit the site multiple times?

```
<!-- Yahoo! GeoIP Service -->
<script src="js/yqlgeo.js"></script>  

<!-- Request users location -->
<script>  
jQuery(window).ready(function(){  
    initiate_geolocation();  
})  

function initiate_geolocation() {  
    if (navigator.geolocation)  
    {  
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handle_geolocation_query, handle_errors);  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        yqlgeo.get('visitor', normalize_yql_response);  
    }  
}  

function handle_errors(error)  
{  
    switch(error.code)  
    {  
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED: alert("User did not share location.");  
        break;  

        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE: alert("Could not detect your location.");  
        break;  

        case error.TIMEOUT: alert("Retrieving location timed out.");  
        break;  

        default: alert("Unknown Error");  
        break;  
    }  
}  

function normalize_yql_response(response)  
{  
    if (response.error)  
    {  
        var error = { code : 0 };  
        handle_error(error);  
        return;  
    }  

    var position = {  
        coords :  
        {  
            latitude: response.place.centroid.latitude,  
            longitude: response.place.centroid.longitude  
        },  
        address :  
        {  
            city: response.place.locality2.content,  
            region: response.place.admin1.content,  
            country: response.place.country.content  
        }  
    };  

    handle_geolocation_query(position);  
}  

function handle_geolocation_query(position){  
    alert('Lat: ' + position.coords.latitude + ' ' +  
          'Lon: ' + position.coords.latitude);  
    }

/* Display Google Static Map with user's location, custom URL encoded pin injected into link */
function handle_geolocation_query(position)  
{  
    var image_url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&center=" + position.coords.latitude + "," +  
                    position.coords.longitude + "&zoom=12&size=225x116&style=feature:water|element:geometry|hue:0x336699|saturation:30|lightness:25&style=feature:road.highway|element:labels|visibility:off&style=feature:transit|element:all|visibility:off|" +  
                    position.coords.latitude + ',' + position.coords.longitude;  

    jQuery("#map").remove();  
    jQuery('#welcome_map').append(  
        jQuery(document.createElement("img")).attr("src", image_url).attr('id','map')  
    );  
}    
</script>
```

Comment: Do u mean cache the script! or cache the actual location of the user?!

Comment: @Arthur Neves ahhh, cache the location of the user

Comment: You could store the location in a cookie.

Comment: Exactly. I was just about to say the same as @Pekka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is some code for you: Just use it to store lat,long!

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function getCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
{
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x==c_name)
    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can personally recommend the jQuery [webStorage plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/webStorage). Check if the location is present in the storage at the beginning. If not, try navigator.geolocation or include the yqlgeo.js by using [$.getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript).
(And of course, save the location once determined. And don't forget that laptops can travel, too.)